# remove script and html comment from a specific div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

this is my code as default i want to remove script, comments and some text from this div using js and get final code below after the js mask

i found this code to remove script but it removes all the script i want to remove from this div only

```
$('script').each(function () {
$(this).remove();
});
```

My code:

```
<div class="data-content">         
        <!-- comment_beginning -->- Sponsored Links -
        &nbsp;
        <br>
        <script src="//data.js"></script>
        <!-- comment -->
        <script>
        //some js 
        </script>
        <br> 
        - Sponsored Links -<!-- /comment_beginning -->
          <div>
           <a href="d.jpg"><img title="example" src="world.jpg" alt="data" width="300" class="animation-data-type0-2"></a>
          </div>
        <p></p>
        <p></p>
        <p></p>
        <!-- comment_after -->- Sponsored Links -
        &nbsp;
        <br>


        <script src="//data.js"></script>
        <!-- comment -->

        <script>
        //some js
        </script><!-- /comment_after -->     

       </div>
```

Final output:

```
<div class="data-content">         

  <div>
   <a href="d.jpg"><img title="example" src="world.jpg" alt="data" width="300" class="animation-data-type0-2"></a>
  </div>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following code to target all script tags that resides under the mentioned div.

```
  $(".data-content script").each(function(){
     var scriptElement = $(this);

     scriptElement.remove();
  });
```

Code for removing the comments:

```
 var container = $(".data-content");

container.contents()
         .filter(function(){ return this.nodeType == 8; })
         .remove();
```

Comment: thanks this worked but i am still left with html comment's and text how to remove that ?

Comment: @MaulikLathiya, I have added the code for removing comments. You can give the people who answered your questions with points by ticking the up arrow on the answer score or marking each answer. This will help other members of the community to know which answers are correct and relevant ;)

Answer (score 1):

Use `$('.data-content').find('script')` to select only `script tags`. To remove comments iterate through the content and remove like below

```js
$('.data-content').find('script').each(function () {
$(this).remove();
});
$('.data-content').contents().each(function() {
    if(this.nodeType === Node.COMMENT_NODE) {
        $(this).remove();
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
My code:

<div class="data-content">         
        <!-- comment_beginning -->- Sponsored Links -
        &nbsp;
        <br>
        <script src="//data.js"></script>
        <!-- comment -->
        <script>
        //some js 
        </script>
        <br> 
        - Sponsored Links -<!-- /comment_beginning -->
          <div>
           <a href="d.jpg"><img title="example" src="world.jpg" alt="data" width="300" class="animation-data-type0-2"></a>
          </div>
        <p></p>
        <p></p>
        <p></p>
        <!-- comment_after -->- Sponsored Links -
        &nbsp;
        <br>


        <script src="//data.js"></script>
        <!-- comment -->

        <script>
        //some js
        </script><!-- /comment_after -->     

       </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solved**

thanks for the help the text was still their and this is how i removed the text

```
$(".data-content").contents().filter(function () {
        return this.nodeType === 3; // Text nodes only
    }).remove();
```